# Web interaction for desktop and touchscreen

Tags: touch-screen, browser

With the increasing adoption of touch screen devices we identified a chart in our product that doesn't work very well on the web and we are trying to decide on the best method of interaction.

Our chart is similar to this [JIT Demo](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example1.html), previously we used a
**Right Click** = ***Centre a Node*** and
**Left Click** = ***navigator to URL of an element***.

We changed to try and remove the right click to try and comply more with web standards. Currently we have a
**Left Click = *Centre a Node*** and a
**Hover with tooltip = *navigate***.

However we obviously discovered that a hover can't be done on a touch screen device. Does anyone have any suggestions on a nice approach for this? The centring operation will either not happen, or happen prior to a navigator from the chart to another page.

Comment: I don't see anything on hover for the link you provided, so it's difficult to say.

Comment: Grab an iPad and download Numbers and play with it for a while. Numbers is a touch-based spreadsheet and may give you some good ideas for interaction patterns.

Comment: Which interaction do you need to fix?

Comment: @AndrewBacon: No there is no hover in the link provided - this is something we've added. In fact in the example there is no concept of navigating to a URL which is something that we allow.

Comment: @dnbrv: We need to fix the navigation interaction as we can't hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Add a link to the selected entity (or even just change the visual and add an arrow) so the click on the link (or the second click on the entity) can navigate away
   Pro - Simple to understand
   Con - Prone to errors as taping is not always done intentionally
2. Use long tap to bring on a menu (similar to copy / paste menu)
   Pro - No errors
   Con - Can be missed

Comment: I've already considered the first, this is something we can actually already do. At the moment I'm thinking of the long click (which I believe is a right click) for touch screen devices if I can determine that from the web.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming your chart contents or screen size make it easier to interact with with a finger more feasible than the chart in your demo.

The easiest solution I can figure is to add a function when a node is centred that presents a "popover"-style tooltip with a "Visit URL" option or something:

[image: Mockup of the popover behaviour]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8e511.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

(My apologies for the crude mockup!)

Comment: Similar to Nurit's answer, and is something I've thought about. Often however people don't want to centre a Node to navigate to it.

Comment: You can theoretically show up the button on touch press and only centre the node on touch *up* to allow a touch, slide down, release interaction. Expect, though, that if you do that most users will still press twice; once to centre and once to navigate.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, although I'd have to look at the events that the browser supports (we have to support back to IE6 and use various canvas replacement technologies). I'd +1 for the suggestion if I could.

Comment: IE6 supports all the same mouse events as modern browsers. It doesn't support the dedicated {{touch}} events, but that's OK, surely?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the entire chart in a persistently visible toolbar?

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: You are showing what can be done with the chart (vs on hover, where nothing is indicated until action taken).

Comment: It's an option, but not a particularly nice one.